# Is Couchbase right choice for mobile apps which don't need to sync always?

Tags: android, couchbase, couchbase-sync-gateway

I just want a NoSql database for my new android app. Clients will just get a bit of data stored in remote server, they don't need to save it at all, since the data stored in the server is too big for a mobile device...

I prefer NoSql to let users reach data quickly where they may be searching different data types together..

I found Couchbase which works both on mobile device and remote server (Couchbase Lite & Server). But found that it is mostly used for P2P apps.

Isn't Couchbase useful for non-sync apps, or can I use it without "Sync Gateway", just use it like a traditional server, where clients send request and get answered?

Or any other database systems proper for me?

Comment: I don't think that SQLite is slow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, the answer to your question: **Yes**.

Couchbase is just a Nosql database which stores some json-like data. You can use it like any database and ignore its sync-gateway feature. (Actually I find it has those features after our project worked for a long time.  )

There are many Nosql databases which have different use cases, [this link](https://kkovacs.eu/cassandra-vs-mongodb-vs-couchdb-vs-redis/) maybe helpful to your decision, it is very detailed and has many use cases. So you can use Couchbase without sync, but you have to be sure that you have choosed the right one.

Comment: Thanks.. Especially the link is very helpful..

Answer (score 0):

Couchbase Lite is designed to be a full-featured embedded NoSQL database.  You can use it entirely standalone just fine. Take a look at the documentation and blog posts on Couchbase's developer portal for more information.

I'm not sure where you're getting that it's mostly for P2P apps. I think that's a great use.  It seems to me to even be underused as a feature.  But this is not the most common use of CBL.

If you want to add some kind of syncing or replication, there are many ways to achieve this.  Full sync is a hard problem, though, so you'll likely find it easiest to use Sync Gateway.  This is quite easy.

The comparison list provided by Twisted M. ([replicated here](https://kkovacs.eu/cassandra-vs-mongodb-vs-couchdb-vs-redis/)) is a good one, but not appropriate for mobile.  Most of the databases listed do not have (currently) any mobile/embedded solution.